# Improve my CSS animation of title appearance

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm looking for some guys interested in looking at my code and give their opinion about it.

To sum up my project was about making cool animation of titles appearance with an effect of a colored block coming from one side while expanding and disappearing from the others side while contracting and let the text appear.

My goal was to achieve something simple, that can be use again easily on differents elements just by giving them the right Classes.

I use only CSS for the animation to improve load time.

**I absolutely wanted the animation to automatically adapts to the size of the text it contain !**

Problems I encounter :

Width animation is easy from left to right but not from right to left because there's no origin define in CSS 'animation' (like in 'transform') to solve the problem I use two elements :

- First one with position absolute, left:0
- Second one with position absolute, right:0

Each one makes only one part of the animation. I find it a bit sad to use two elements to pretend the animation of only one element but I didn't figured out a different way of doing this.

So here is my code :

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 1200px; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #FE4D3D;
 font-family: arial;
}


#container{
 margin-left: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}



.animated-block-from-left{
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index: 2;
 height: 100%; 
   width: 0%;
   animation: grandir 1s ease ;

}

@keyframes grandir{
 0%{width: 0%;}
 100%{width: 100%;}
}

.animated-block-from-right{
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 z-index: 2;
 height: 100%; 
   width: 0%;
   animation: retrecir 1s 1s ease ;

}


@keyframes retrecir{
 0%{width: 100%;}
 100%{width: 0%;}
}



.yellow{
 background-color: #FFFE02;
}


h1{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 80px;
 color: transparent;
 animation: textappear 0.1s 1s forwards;
 z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes textappear{
 100%{color: #FFFE02;}
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

 <h1>
  HELLO JOHN !
  <div id="line" class="animated-block-from-left yellow"> </div>
  <div id="line" class="animated-block-from-right yellow"> </div>

 </h1>

</div>
```

All advices, opinions are the most welcomed !

Thanks you !

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: add a jsfiddle its makes it easier to help you (:

Comment: @Roberrrt yes it is.

Comment: Yep, code review is where it is at as far as I can see. [Have an example anyway](https://jsbin.com/muxare/edit?css,output)

Comment: Should I delete my post and create a new one code ? thanks misterMansam do you have a ressource I can read to improve my knowledge of the technique you use ?

Comment: @GordonFreeman Yes, I would recommend doing that.

Comment: okay sorry guys !